# Integer solutions of $a^6 + 4 b^3 = 1$

Tags: diophantine-equations

This question is simplified case of

[Integer solutions of $a^6 + 4 b^3 = c^6$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2589582/integer-solutions-of-a6-4-b3-c6)

Is there integer solutions for
$$a^6 + 4 b^3 = 1$$

The way I am trying to prove is based on Fermat's Theorem, but I can not get the final result.

Comment: We must have $a\equiv 1,3 \pmod4$ and $(a,b)=1$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From $a^6+4b^3=1$, we see that $a$ must be odd. Let's rewrite the equation as

$$(a^3-1)(a^3+1)=-4b^3$$

Since $a^3$ is odd, we have $\gcd(a^3-1,a^3+1)=2$, so we have

$$\begin{align}
a^3-1&=2c^3\\
a^3+1&=2d^3
\end{align}$$

where $cd=-b$ with $\gcd(c,d)=1$. But this implies

$$a^3=c^3+d^3$$

which, as Fermat observed, has no nontrivial integer solutions. So we're left with $(a,b)=(\pm1,0)$ as the only integer solution.

**Remark** (added later): As the OP brilliantly observes, there is really no need to rely on Fermat.  If you *subtract* the two equations instead of adding them, you get $d^3-c^3=1$, which immediately eliminates anything nontrivial, since cubes have a hard time differing by $1$.

Comment: I think would be simpler just to observe the difference $d^3-c^3=1$ which is impossible. So no need to refer to Fermat theorem

Comment: @GevorgHmayakyan, yes!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Actually this proof can be generalized for any $p$ : $a^{2p}+4b^p=1$ has no integer solutions for any $p$.